# Что такое упакованные числа?

Tags: c, числа, c++

Дали такое задание: 
Дан массив N упакованных чисел, распаковать их и вывести на экран в две строки. `N>=10`

Что такое упакованные числа? Нигде не могу найти, расскажите кто знает..
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BСD](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) числа что ли?

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408361/decimal-to-bcd-conversion) и [вот](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/50350/), читайте.